# How to know where SVN will commit to?

Tags: svn, switch-statement

I often switch to different branches, how can I check to which branch SVN will commit? Right now I'm grepping the history for my last `svn switch` command, but is there not a definitive way to know from within SVN itelf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check this simply by using:

```
svn info
```

within your working copy and will printout all the information you need.